# Are qload V9.1.1 and dmpmqmsg compatible?

Tags: ibm-mq

Are qload V9.1.1 and dmpmqmsg compatible and vice versa?

If a message is unloaded by qload, can it be loaded with dmpmqmsg and also the reverse way?

Comment: Yes. Are you seeing some issue that makes you ask this question?

Comment: yes.. the message created with qload is not getting loaded with dmpmqmsg

Comment: Can you show us the output when you try to load with dmpmqmsg. Also, why not just load it up with qload if you have both? qload can run over a client connection if its on a different platform.